# Angular call a variable from different .js file

Tags: angularjs, var

I am creating a variable rejecting another one, in "First.js" file:

```
var nosubs = _.reject(subs, function (bi) { return bi.ParentBoardbookItemId === '0'; });
```

Is it possible to call this variable (nosubs) to "Second.js" file?
How can I do that?

Notice that i a

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what are you going to achieve by referring variable? This will help me to give a better answer

Comment: The above is a Javascript with underscore. Do you want to just use the variable nosubs from another file or you want to use angular?

Answer (score 1):

There is tons of way of doing it. The best in angular is to not use variables. But to store your data in a service.

```
// simplified version of defining the service
app.service("myService", function(){
    this.setData = function(data){
        this.data = data;
    };
    this.getData = function(){
         return this.data;
    };
    return this;
});
// now you just have to inject it in your controllers/run blocks and you can use myService.data.
```

Another solution would be to store it in the $rootScope.

If you want/need something else we'll need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can store varible in rootscope to access in other files.

```
$rootScope.nosubs = _.reject(subs, function (bi) { return bi.ParentBoardbookItemId === '0'; });
```